# ¿donde esta el error? intercambio de variables

Tags: c

Disculpen pero soy nuevo en c y tengo que resolver este ejercicio

> Escribir el código del programa que solicita el valor de dos números enteros y los intercambia posteriormente, mostrando tanto el valor inicial de cada variable como su valor final.

Pero al correrlo no me imprime los valores, me pide ingresar 2 numeros para que despues los imprima y luego los intercambie y los imprima pero no imprime los valores

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a,b;
    printf("ingresa el primer valor: \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("ingresa el segundo valor: \n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("el primer valor es: \n", a );
    printf("el segundo valor es: \n", b);
    a=b;
    b=a;
    printf("el nuevo valor de a es: \n", a );
    printf("el nuevo valor de b es: \n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ya te he respuesto, el problema es que en el _printf()_ debias agregar el "%d" para que este se reemplace por el numero que quieres imprimir, espero te sirva

Comment: lo hice pero dice que no se ve al publico porque aun no tengo reputacion de 15

Comment: @lalohernandez tu historial indica que de 4 preguntas realizadas aun no has marcado ninguna como solucionada. ¿Es realmente así? Por lo que estoy viendo no. Te agradeceríamos que fueses marcando algunas respuestas como soluciones (solo puedes marcar una por preguna). Así ayudas al buen funcionamiento de StackOverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error que tienes es que realizas el *printf()* sin el modificador "%d" que sirve para imprimir numeros enteros.

Aqui la solución:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a, b, aux;

    printf("ingresa el primer valor: \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("ingresa el segundo valor: \n");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    printf("el primer valor es: %d\n", a );
    printf("el segundo valor es: %d\n", b);

    aux = a;
    a   = b;
    b   = aux;

    printf("el nuevo valor de a es: %d\n", a );
    printf("el nuevo valor de b es: %d\n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

> Resultado

```
ingresa el primer valor: 
10
ingresa el segundo valor: 
15
el primer valor es: 10
el segundo valor es: 15
el nuevo valor de a es: 15
el nuevo valor de b es: 10
```

Mas información sobre los modificadores: [Aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: muchas gracias y como haria para que a tomara el valor de b y b el de a ya que se pierde el valor al cambiar la primer variable

Comment: @lalohernandez Usando una variable auxiliar

Comment: @lalohernandez Ya lo he corregido, se agrega la variable auxiliar y asi se mantiene el valor original

Comment: ahora esta completo!!!